# Passing FormsAuthentication cookie to a WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, forms-authentication, wcf-security

I have a website that talks to a remote WCF web service. Both use the same custom FormsAuthentication Provider. I would like to authenticate with the WCF service impersonating the user currently logged in the site. I already did this manually, using UserName client credentials but I need to know the user password.
So, what works so fart is this: an authenticated user makes a request, I create a Service Client and set his credentials:

```
serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

But what I really want is to pass the FormsAuthentication cookie directly, because I don't want to store the user password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello Ariel, how did you get on with this one? I know someone with similar issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Windows Communication Foundation Authentication Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx).

**EDIT:**

After re-reading the question more carefully (and after Ariel's comment) I'd like to retract the above suggestion. The WCF Authentication Service won't add much to this scenario.

I haven't done this between WCF and ASP.NET, however I have configured ASP.NET applications to share forms authenticated users, perhaps I can help in some way.

To ensure that both applications can encrypt/decrypt the forms authentication cookie in the same way you should [configure the `<machineKey>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) for both applications (in web.config or machine.config depending on whether you want to do this at the machine or application level). You should look at the `validation`, `validationKey`, `decryption` and `decryptionKey` attributes.

Ensure that your `<forms>` elements in both web.config files are configured similarly. Specifically the `name`, `path` and `domain` attributes.

It's likely that this only applies to cookies passed to/from a web browser (but may be useful in this case): To allow cookies to be passed between the websites *www.foo.com* and *bar.foo.com* you would configure the `forms` element as follows to allow cookies to be set on one site and successfully passed to the other:

```
<forms ... domain=".foo.com" ... />
```

Passing the cookie to the WCF service is likely to be the tricky bit. I'm not very experienced with WCF, so [I've adapted code from kennyw.com](http://kennyw.com/indigo/153):

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "<Forms Authentication Cookie>");

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(serviceClient.InnerChannel))
{
  OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
  serviceClient.MethodName();
}
```

If you're hosting WCF within IIS (and not self-hosting) you can pass the WCF request through the ASP.NET processing pipeline by setting

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" ... />
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you're self hosting you could examine the request headers using the incoming message's properties in `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties` and get the forms authentication cookie value and decrypt it using [`FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx).

I have no idea whether any of this would work, but would love to hear if it does!

Comment: I don't see how the Authentication Service could help.
My scenario is this:
USER -> Web Site A -> WCF Service B hosted elsewhere
User logs in to A, A makes a call to B using the User credentials.
Where would you add the Authentication service?

Comment: Hi Ariel. Sorry I tried to answer too quickly without really reading your question. I'll edit it with an update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that and share the results here.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple enough to do if you host the WCF service within the authenticated IIS site.

Enable compatibility by adding the following to your system.ServiceModel section in your web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>  
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then decorate each service you wish to accept the cookie with the following

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
    RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Now the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity object will be correctly populated and you can also use PrinciplePermission demands to limit access by role or to particular users.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, I can't use the same IIS. A requirement for the system I'm building was to host the web site and service in separate machines.
I'm considering using a shared token but I using Forms was the simplest solution to implement coming from ASP.net.

Comment: Ah sod! Can you at least put them on the same domain name? If so you can set the forms auth cookie scope and share it that way.

Comment: I think so, the application will be hosted in an intranet under a single root domain. We can set identical machine keys also but keep in mind the user is accessing the website and the website uses the WCF as a data source impersonating the user. It works fine with Windows Authentication but passing the FormsAuthentication cookie is a different story. I'll try dariom suggestion (or any other if available).

Comment: blowdart, just wanted to let you know that although this reply didn't answer the poster's question, it answered mine. I appreciate your not having removed it!