# How to set http cookies (headers) in HTTP request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, http, cookies, header

I'm trying to set up a WCF service hosted in IIS in ASP.Net compatibility mode that is protected via Forms Authentication and accessed via a .Net User Control in IE. (see [Secure IIS hosted WCF service for access via IE hosted user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874774/secure-iis-hosted-wcf-service-for-access-via-ie-hosted-winforms-user-control)).

The User Control in IE is needed because it uses a specific third-party control for which there doesn't exist anything comparable in Silverlight or AJAX.

So I need the UserControl to set the authentication and session id cookies in the http request headers before it accesses the WCF service. My approach is to set up a Message inspector that does this.

So I've defined the Message Inspector:

```
public class CookieInspector : IClientMessageInspector {

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) {
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(
            ref Message request, 
            IClientChannel channel) {

        HttpRequestMessageProperty messageProperty;

        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name)) {
            messageProperty = (HttpRequestMessageProperty) request.Properties[
                HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name
            ];
        }
        else {
            messageProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            request.Properties.Add(
                HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, 
                messageProperty
            );
        }

        // Set test headers for now...
        messageProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "Bob=Great");
        messageProperty.Headers.Add("x-chris", "Beard");

        return null;
    }
}
```

and an Endpoint behaviour:

```
public class CookieBehavior : IEndpointBehavior {
    public void AddBindingParameters(
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
            BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
            ClientRuntime clientRuntime) {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CookieInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
            EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) {
    }
}
```

and I configure and create my channel and WCF client in code:

```
var ea = new EndpointAddress("http://.../MyService.svc");

// EDIT: Http cookies can't be set with WSHttpBinding :-(
// var binding = WSHttpBinding();
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();


// Disable automatically managed cookies (which enables user cookies)
binding.AllowCookies = false;


binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 5000000;
var cf = new ChannelFactory<ITranslationServices>(binding, ea);
cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CookieBehavior());    

ITranslationServices service = cf.CreateChannel();
```

However when I look at my request with Fiddler, the http header and cookie aren't set, and I have no clue why. I've read various articles on the Net, Stackoverflow etc that basically say that it should work, but it doesn't. Either I'm missing something obvious, or there's a bug in WCF or something else?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I figured it out, if I use a basicHttpBinding instead of a WSHttpBinding it works. No idea why though...

Comment: Did you ever find out why this didn't work with WSHttpBinding? I'm running into the same problem, but it works with basicHttpBinding

Comment: No sorry finally we dropped ASP.NET completely for the project and went with a WinForms + WCF + ClickOnce architecture and the point became moot.

Answer (score 0):

`WSHttpBinding` may be composed of more than one physical message to one logical message. So when successive physical calls are made, they may not be carrying the cookie appropriately