# Double Impersonation - from Web Site to Service to Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, impersonation

I have an ASP MVC web site, let's call it WebSite. And two services Service1 and Service2. From the WebSite I call Service1 and from Service1 I call Service2. In WebSite I use Windows Authentication. I want to call Service2 from WebSite with User's rights. I've read about double impersonation and delegation, but I want to clarify something.. If I'm hosting WebSite and both Services at same machine, do I still need to use delegation? And how I actually do this in code/web.config??
I call Service1 from WebSite with ((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate() and this works fine, but when I try to this calling Service2 from Service1, ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() throws exception.
So, how can I do this?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was, that I didn't set an Impersonation level of the service to Impersonate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `HttpContext.Current` in your webservice. It's `null`, as the exception has probably told you. You can get the current user from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in web services.

Comment: My mistake.. I used ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Imperosnate().. but when I call Service2 it throws exception Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Selectors ...

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Service1` and the `Service2` are not open to public access, you could call them using some custom argument indicating the user, his/her roles or the his/her privileges. I suppose this would be the simplest solution.

A more structured solution would be to use the same authentication realm for both sites. It is not very easy. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087271/passing-formsauthentication-cookie-to-a-wcf-service) would give you some better insight on how to do it.

Hope I helped!